# Cloning the Marlin git repo while keeping my configuration.h settings?

Tags: marlin, reprap

I cloned the Marlin repository and changed all my settings in `configuration.h` to match my old settings. Now when the RC branch gets updated, is there a way to upstream pull the changes without losing my settings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19216491/1417624) answer, you need the following procedure:

1. Stash your local changes using `git stash`
2. Pull from remote repository using `git pull`
3. Merge your stashed configuration file using `git stash pop`

Of course, if there are changes in the `configuration.h` file on the remote repository and cause conflicts, you will need to resolve them, but it should be straight forward.

Comment: Thank you! I always wondered when to use stash - it seems like this would be an appropriate scenario.